# Finding string length without using strlen and using function in C

Tags: c

I wrote this code but it gives length 0.I  am beginner and couldn't find what is wrong with this?This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int strlgnth(char *s);      /* func prototype */

int strlgnth(char *s)
{
    int i;
    {
        for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++);
        i = i++;
    }
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    char s[1000], i, n;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", s);

    {
        i = strlgnth(s);
    }
    printf("Length of string: %d", n);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You have several unnecessary block brackets, why is that?

Comment: Why is there a `for` statement with no loop body??

Comment: @HotLicks There is nothing to do in the loop body. `s[i]!='\0';i++` covers all it should do.

Comment: Duplicated info relative to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373535/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-calling-strlen-in-my-for-loop-condition-in-c

Comment: @Nabla - Ah, yes.  He actually got that part kinda right.  Hard to see it in the clutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the result of your calculation to `i`, but print out `n`.

Moreover, as `n` had never been initilaised, the code (also) runs into undefined behaviour reading it to have it printed out.

---

This line

```
i=i++;
```

is useless.

---

The value to assign the result of `strlgnth()` to should have the same type, that is `int`.

Or even better make `strlgnth()` and all `i`s to be `size_t`.

`size_t` is guaranteed to be wide enough to hold any size the platform may use.

---

Finally this line

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

is dangerous as it allows the user to overlfow `s`. To avoid this tell `scanf()` the maximum number of charaters to scan in, that is the buffer's size - 1. The 1 character in spare is necessaory to hold the `0`-terminator:

```
scanf("%999s", s);
```

---

Perhaps you should clean-up the layout of your sources. This might help gaining the overview.

Answer (score 3):

```
int strlgnth(char *s)
{ 
  int i;    
  for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
     ;   
  return i;
}
```

and

```
printf("Length of string: %d",i);
```

Comment: And declare `i` in `main` as `int i;`

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves yes that would be better -- for small strings this should still work.

Answer (score 2):

Delete this line:

```
    i=i++;
```

It's (a) unnecessary and (b) it results in undefined bahviour.

Also, as others have noted, you are confusing `i` and `n` in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention, his line:

```
 i=i++;
```

is wrong. The behavior is undefined. Try to remove it, as i is incremented in your for loop definition itself.